# How to extract max amount of column for each group in powerquery?

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, m

I am working on some data in powerquery in Excel. I need to make a query that returns unique values of the original table. The original table has a structure like below.

```
Year    month    name   qty
2019    Jan        n    100
2019    Jan        n    200
2019    Jan        m    300
2019    Jan        m    400
2019    feb        n    1000
2019    feb        n    20
2019    feb        m    300
2019    feb        m    500
2020    Jan        n    100
2020    Jan        n    200
2020    Jan        m    300
2020    Jan        m    400
2020    feb        n    1000
2020    feb        n    20
2020    feb        m    300
2020    feb        m    500
```

I need to extract an output like below

```
year    month   product MaxQty
2019    feb        m    500
2019    feb        n    1000
2019    Jan        m    400
2019    Jan        n    200
2020    feb        m    500
2020    feb        n    1000
2020    Jan        m    400
2020    Jan        n    200
```

In Sql, I can extract this output with below line of code.

```
SELECT year,month,name,max(qty) as MaxQty
FROM Table1 group by year,month,name;
```

How can I do it in power query of excel?

I used the following command:

```
=List.Distinct(Table1[Year])
```

but it worked on one column and I could not expand it to multiple columns to extract the max price of each product in year and month.

I need to do it in Power query. I would appreciate if you could advice.

Comment: Countifs() would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click select the year, month and name columns

Right click group by

take the maximum of the qty column

[image]